# How can I give many inputs in just one line in the console like in C++?

Tags: python

In C++ code, I can give `1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8` then press enter in console to have output like,

```
1 2
3 4
5 6
7 8
```

But in Python code when I tried to generate the same output by the inputting in the console like `1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8` and enter but it generated an error...
Rather I can give input and have output in console like this in Python:

```
1 2
1 2
3 4
3 4
5 6
5 6
7 8
7 8
```

I can see my code is not enough in Python...

I tried putting `input().split()` in a loop.

```
/* C++ */
int x,y;
for (int i=0; i<4; i++){
    cin>>x>>y;
    cout<<x<<y<<endl;
}
```

```
# Python
for i in range(4):
    x, y = input().split()
    print(x, y)
```

I expected Python could take those inputs just in only one line and generate the output in the console like in C++.

Comment: Don't try to use python like C++.  They are different languages and have different ways to do the same thing.  I would suggest getting yourself a good python book and starting learning from there.

Comment: Can you suggest a book @NathanOliver? I will read it.

Comment: @MohammedDilshad See the Free Python Programming Books section [here](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/python/info)

Comment: Can you suggest a book name pls..? @NathanOliver

Comment: @MohammedDilshad Sorry, I'm not python coder so I can't suggest anything.  Maybe someone else who sees this will.

Comment: apology accepted

Answer (score 2):

take a look to zipping and iterators before using this code :

```
iterator = iter(input().split())
for x,y in zip(iterator,iterator):
    print(x,y)
```

> input :

`1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8`

> output :

```
1 2
3 4
5 6
7 8
```

Comment: for more explanation please see this link : [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38024554/python-iterator-and-zip]

Answer (score 1):

This is because in contrary with `c++`, in Python every time you call `input` it waits for new input from the user. So, if you expect to get a 8 numbers input and print it in couples you should take the `input` one time before the loop. Like so:

```py
nums = input().split()
for i in range(0, len(nums), 2):
    print(nums[i], nums[i+1])
```

And this on an input of `1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8` gives:

```
1 2
3 4
5 6
7 8
```